# Convert string to HTMl link in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display the string as HTMl link in angularjs. But it is rendering 
as string. Can some one help me to solve this.

[Rendered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ay1w.png)

HTML:

```
<canvas class="chart chart-bar"
                    data="graph.data"
                    labels="graph.labels"
                    series="graph.series"
                    options="graph.options"
                    legend="graph.legend"
                    click="onClick"
                    chart="chart"></canvas>
```

js:

```
 $scope.graph.labels.push('<span ng-click="openView()">' + value.ProjectName + '</span>');
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: <canvas class="chart chart-bar"
                    data="graph.data"
                    labels="graph.labels"
                    series="graph.series"
                    options="graph.options"
                    legend="graph.legend"
                    click="onClick"
                    chart="chart"></canvas>

Comment: Can you edit your question and include this comment there?

Answer (score 0):

try use **\'** instead of quotation marks (**"**)

Comment: I changes like this even it is not working:  $scope.graph.labels.push('<span ng-click=\openView()\>' + value.ProjectName + '</span>');

Comment: forgotten
$scope.graph.labels.push('<span ng-click=\'openView()\'>' + value.ProjectName + '</span>');

Comment: still it is not working. It is displaying as a string only.

Comment: if you can share all project on bitbucket or github (okosowski@gmail.com)
see what I can do :)

Comment: Below is the github URl I added my entire code:                         https://github.com/sanjeev1992/angular-chart.js/blob/31b26b663462ced1ae805bd43563d7fa781687b4/Examples/Injdex.cshtml

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a hard day at work and dont have much time, but ...
first: making "push" on every elements in my opinion isnt the best idea. Better will by use ng-repeat with ng-if condition like:
<div ng-repeat="stuff in stuffs" ng-if="stuffs && stuffs.length"><span>{{stuff.title}}</span> <span>{{stuff.content}}</span></div>
and in JS $scope.stuffs.push({title: 'Hello', content: 'world'}).

Comment: second: when you write (...)push('<span ng-click=\'openView()\'>' (...), every span element was add to DOM but as a plain text (after angular render the DOM elements), if you have to do this in this way I advise you to try jquery .append()

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a directive. Let's take a look to the code bellow:

View code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.14" data-semver="1.3.14" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
    <h1>Directive test</h1>

    <!--directive element-->
    <my-custom-element></my-custom-element>
  </body>

</html>
```

We have a custom element named "my-custom-element", this element will be fullfilled by a directive called `"myCustomElement"` placed in the code bellow:

```
angular
  .module("myApp", [])
  .directive("myCustomElement", myCustomElement)
  .controller("myCtrl", myCtrl)

  function myCustomElement(){
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      template: "<div class = 'myCtrl.attrs.class' data = 'myCtrl.attrs.data'>Template content</div>",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        //here you can add your own logic to modify your data
      }
    }
  }

  function myCtrl(){
    var vm = this;

    vm.attrs = {
      class: "chart chart-bar",
      data: "graph.data"
    };
  }
```

As you can see the `template` key replaces the content of our custom element (my-custom-element). On that way you will be able to replace whatever content you want in a clean way.

Try to not modify the dom like a jquery developer.

I hope that this answer may be useful for you.

Here is the plunkr link: https://plnkr.co/edit/ffeq3e4siGfBn5BD7OU2?p=preview